# how to convert an user input for a file name into a hardcoded file name in VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a very simple question and as i have just started programming in VBA i would like and appreciate any help regarding this. How can i change a user prompt for input and output file name as hardcoded in a macro.

Comment: Hi, I've found this [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?313861-VB6-Modify-VBA-Macro-Code-From-VB), perhaps it could give you an idea.

Comment: Do you mean remove the user prompts and replace with hardcoded values permanently as a one time fix, or do you mean still prompt, but have that go in and change the code itself?